# solutions of $a+b=c^2 , a^2+c^2=b^2$ ; $a,b,c$ are natural numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, systems-of-equations

So it all started with a fun observation, $12+13=5^2$ and these are Pythagorean triplets($5,12,13$), so I thought are there more such numbers? 
with brute force I was able to get $(24,25,7)$ and $(40,41,9)$.

Then I was able to find 3 families of solutions.

$(50k^2+50k+12 , 50k^2+50k+13 , 10k+5)$

$(10k+4 , 10k+5 , \sqrt{20k+9})$

$(10k, 10k+1 , \sqrt{20k+1})$

ps: I found these by using the property of Pythagorean triplets that they have at least one multiple of 5 in it.

My question is are there more sets of solution and how do I know I haven't missed any?

Comment: Hint: use the paramatrisation of Pythagorean triplets.

Comment: $(a,b,c) = (2k^2+2k,2k^2+2k+1,2k+1)$

Comment: @achillehui yeah just got that answer too...didn't think about parameterizing Pythagorean triplets as said...but by any chance did I get all of them? I think I do...can't prove it though

Comment: @YiFan Thanks didn't think about that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$a^2+c^2=b^2$$
$$\implies a^2+a+b=b^2$$
$$\implies \Big(a+\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2= \Big(b-\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2$$
$$\implies a+\frac{1}{2}=b-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\implies b=a+1$$
Hence,
$$2a+1=c^2$$
Therefore, $c$ is odd, let $c=2k+1$. Putting it in above equation, you get, $$a=2k^2+2k$$
$$\implies b=a+1=2k^2+2k+1$$
This is the required general solution.

Comment: From $$a^2+a+b-b^2=0,$$  $$a=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{(2b-1)^2}}2=\dfrac{-1\pm(2b-1)}2=b-1,-b$$  or $$a^2+a+b-b^2=(a+b)(a-b+1)$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, I really do not understand your comment. Yes, these are other ways of showing that $a = b-1$, because $a$ and $b$ are given to be natural numbers.

Answer (score 2):

WLOG $a=k(m^2-n^2), b=k(m^2+n^2),c=2mnk$

We need $$2km^2=(2mnk)^2$$

$$1=2kn^2$$ which is untenable

If $a=2mnk, c=k(m^2-n^2),b=?$

$\implies k(m+n)^2=k^2(m^2-n^2)^2$

As $m+n>0,$

$$1=k(m-n)^2$$

$\implies k=1,m-n=\pm1$

Answer (score 2):

$a^2 + c^2 = b^2$

$c^2 = b^2 - a^2 = (b-a)(a+b)$ but $a+b = c^2$ so if we assume $a+b \ne 0$, we have $b-a = 1$ and $b = a+1$ and we have

$a^2 + c^2 = (a+1)^2$ and $2a + 1 = c^2$

If we replace $c^2$ with $2a+1$ we have $a^2 + 2a + 1 = (a+1)^2$ which is always true.  So $2a+1=c^2$ can be any number that is both; an odd number at least equal to $3$ ($a \ge 1$); and a perfect square, and $c=\sqrt {2a+1}$ is a square root of an odd perfect square greater than $3$ which can be any odd integer greater than $1$.

So for any $k \in \mathbb N$ we can have $c = 2k +1$, $a=  \frac {c^2 -1}2= 2k(k+1)$  and $b = \frac {c^2  +1}2 = 2k^2 + 2k + 1$.

Those are all of them.

If $k\equiv 0,4 \pmod 5$ then $a\equiv 0 \pmod 5$.  If $k\equiv 1,3\pmod 5$ then $b\equiv 0 \pmod 5$ and if $k \equiv 2\pmod 5$ then $c \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting c^2 into the second equation we obtain a^2+a+b=b^2 to that we have a(a+1)=b(b-1), now this is a quadratic in terms of a (or b) which can be solved by the quadratic formula. So we have a^2+a+(b-b^2)=0 and solving gives a=-b or a=b-1. Now if a=-b then c^2=0 so c=0, hence we have found the trivial solution (a,b,c)=(0,0,0). 
Now if a=b-1, then from c^2=a+b=b-1+b=2b-1 we obtain that c=+-sqrt(2b-1), but since we are considering natural numbers, we can take the positive root c=sqrt(2b-1). Finally either we have the trivial solution or all solutions are of the form (a,b,c)= (b-1,b, sqrt(2b-1)) whenever sqrt(2b-1) gives a natural number, i.e 2b-1=n^2, odd square numbers. 
I believe your set of solutions are fine, just the trivial solution is missing as far as I can tell.

Comment: if I put b=10k+5 and 10k+1 then I get 1st and second families of solutions respectively.